# how to fix createElement is not a function in vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I've got below code, which I used it in `Vue 2` projects to add dynamic styles to components, and when I tried to use it in `Vue 3`, I've got `createElemenet is not a function` error.

In `Vue 2` :

```
app.js
Vue.component('v-style', {
    render: function (createElement) {
        return createElement('style', this.$slots.default)
    }
});
```

In `Vue 3` :

```
app.js
app
    .component('err-text', ErrorText)
    .component('v-style', {
    render: function (createElement : any) {
        return createElement('style', this.$slots.default)
    }
});
```

The result of above code provide me option to add my styles like below :

```
<template>
 <v-style>
   .foo {
    color: red;
   }
 </v-style>
</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue 3 `createElement` is replaced by the `h` function imported from `vue` :

```js
import {h} from 'vue'

app.component('err-text', ErrorText)
    .component('v-style', {
    render: function () {
        return h('style', this.$slots.default())
    }
});
```